# Ajax type controls for .NET winforms

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2008

Are there any 3rd part WinForms controls out there that give me ajax type effects.
For example I want an effect where if I have a list box or a DataGrid control and someone clicks a field to mark it as complete I want that field to fade away not just instantly disappear.
The standard controls get the job done but are not the best looking.

I hope that came accross clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [**WPF** (Windows Presentation Foundation)](http://windowsclient.net/). This is Microsoft's new framework for developing graphically rich user interfaces, and would in fact be capable of a lot fancier effects than you see with AJAX.

WPF is a radically different technology to its predecessor WinForms, but it's well worth the time spent learning!

Comment: Thanks noldorin, I'll definately be trying this out.

Answer (score 0):

There are pleny of third party controls..

DevExpress - http://www.devexpress.com/

Telerik - http://www.telerik.com/

Component Factory - https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton

Infragistics NetAdvantage - http://www.infragistics.com/

ComponentOne - http://www.componentone.com/